# What are the differences between nohup and bg?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

haven't used nohup command until today, but now I need to use it to run a command in the background.

As far as i know, i can also use the bg command to run a process in background. So my question is, what are the differences between nohup and bg commands?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595374/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-ampersand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my application die without nohup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196755/why-does-my-application-die-without-nohup)

Comment: Also related: [How to “correctly” start an application from a shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152310/80216)  Disclosure: I am the author of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Running a command in the background allows you working on in that shell, but does **NOT** prevent the command from being killed once you exit the session (e.g. log out from the desktop session, end an ssh-session, exit the tty).

`nohup` is meant for starting long-running processes that should run on a server even when the user logs out.

Comment: To add to this, `nohup` is short for **no hang up** which prevents the process from receiving the `SIGHUP` or **Signal Hang UP** signal -- which is the signal sent when closing/exiting the terminal.